# filter the data on the basis of two column with the help of linux command

Tags: awk, grep

I have a *.psl file in which there are 22 columns. I want to extract all rows on the basis of column 10  and column 22. SO as some have multiple common reads in column 10 and there is a score in column 22 so which have a higher score for a particular read just print those rows only and remove the remaining reads from my new output file.

```
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005880    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005724    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005173    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
97  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 152 250 hsa_circ_0004932    100 0   98  1   98, 152,    0,  98
94  0   0   0   1   3   2   6   +   4c415d86-0c12-4b07-ab19-0d7fcbe8b1c7    334 220 317 hsa_circ_0001006    100 0   100 3   18,25,51,   220,238,266,    0,19,49,    94
83  3   0   0   2   5   3   10  +   a28de8d0-e08b-43b5-9de2-07df4404ea8c    332 35  126 hsa_circ_0037060    100 4   100 5   7,18,43,3,15,   35,43,65,108,111,   4,11,36,81,85,  86
71  3   0   0   0   0   1   1   -   2116d815-5edb-4124-998b-398be6161c56    490 184 258 hsa_circ_0001592    100 1   76  2   34,40,  232,266,    1,36,   74
```

So I want output like this in which you can see one row is remove from my file which have low score than any other similar reads.

```
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005880    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005724    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
98  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   +   7efcc799-5806-477b-8145-fb13d90fcdb4    466 151 250 hsa_circ_0005173    100 0   99  1   99, 151,    0,  99
94  0   0   0   1   3   2   6   +   4c415d86-0c12-4b07-ab19-0d7fcbe8b1c7    334 220 317 hsa_circ_0001006    100 0   100 3   18,25,51,   220,238,266,    0,19,49,    94
83  3   0   0   2   5   3   10  +   a28de8d0-e08b-43b5-9de2-07df4404ea8c    332 35  126 hsa_circ_0037060    100 4   100 5   7,18,43,3,15,   35,43,65,108,111,   4,11,36,81,85,  86
71  3   0   0   0   0   1   1   -   2116d815-5edb-4124-998b-398be6161c56    490 184 258 hsa_circ_0001592    100 1   76  2   34,40,  232,266,    1,36,   74
```

I search it but there is no similar question I found. So please can you tell me how can I sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You could have provided an example demonstrating this problem with 5 columns instead of 30 (or whatever that is) necessitating a scroll bar. For future questions please create and post a **minimal** example for us to help you with, not just whatever data you have lying around.

Comment: It's not clear from your text (does `which have a higher score` mean `which have the highest score` or `which have a score higher than the lowest score`?) or your example which only removes 1 line if you want to remove all lines except those with the single highest score (keep lines for 1 score) or remove all lines with the single lowest score (potentially keep lines with multiple scores) or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` and processing the input file *twice*, once for finding the highest values for the same column10, and second time to printing the records with those highest values which we found:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ max[$10]=(max[$10]>$NF? max[$10]:$NF); next } 
     max[$10]==$NF' infile infile
```